# Error in read.table in R

Tags: r

I have a txt file with only 59.6KB. and I write my scripts as I did thousand times

```
cancer<-read.table("cancerGenes.txt", row.names=1,header=T)
```

And it gives me the error message:

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 1 did not have 28 elements
```

what went wrong??!!

Comment: Does your file have any uncommon character encoding? I have encountered this error in such cases before.

Comment: like what kinds of uncommon character? how to fix it?

Comment: Perhaps post the first 3 rows of your data set, or a set of fake data in the identical format.

Comment: never mind, I converted into csv file, then it works! I dont know whats going on, but thank you two

Comment: Actually the default separator is any number of spaces, a so-called "whitespace" separator. `> read.table(text="a       b") #
  V1 V2
1  a  b`. Tab-characters are also seen as whitespace unless sep ='\t'

Answer (score 1):

Try using the table(count.fields( ... ) strategy:

```
table(count.fields("yourpath/filename.txt", sep="", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, 
      allowEscapes = TRUE, quote="", comment.char=""))
```

Then add back values to 'quote' or 'comment.char' if needed. The default values for 'quote' are the two character string "'\"" and you may want to first try quote="\"" to keep names with single quotes (like "O'Malley") from causing problems , and the default for comment.char is the octothorpe, "#". Mismatched quotes are common  in unclean data files and you may need to do some further investigation to print out lines with abnormal numbers of elements.

Posting a link to a location where we can examine the file is the next step for you.